# Isomorphism between measure-preserving non-invertible transformations (for example, tent map)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am interested in isomorphisms between transformations with measures of them, especially is the transformations that are not invertible. I found the following definition:

Two measure-preserving transformations $(X,\,\mathbb{B},\,\mu,\,f)$ and $(Y,\,\mathbb{A},\,\nu,\,g)$ are called *isomorphic*  if there exist  measure-preserving mappings $\phi:X\to Y$, $\psi:Y\to X$ such that the following conditions hold:
1. $\psi\circ\phi=id\;$ $\mu$-almost everywhere,
2. $\phi\circ\psi=id\;$ $\nu$-almost everywhere,
3. $\phi\circ f= g\circ \phi\;$ $\mu$-almost everywhere,
4. $\psi\circ g= f\circ \psi\;$ $\nu$-almost everywhere.

Is it right that, if X=Y, instead we can just use the following conditions:
3. $\phi\circ f= g\;$ $\mu$-almost everywhere,
4. $\psi\circ g= f\;$ $\nu$-almost everywhere?

More interestingly, is it possible to have an isomorphism between two mappings one which is non-invertible? For example, the doubling map or the tent map $f(x)=1-|1-2x|$, $0\leq x<1$ on a circle both preserve several measures, including the Lebesgue measure, but are not invertible. Is it possible to prove or disprove them to be isomorphic to an interval exchange transformation? To a rotation of a circle? To each other?

Thank you for answering me.

Comment: Answer to your first question: it isn't right (an inverse is the same no matter if $X=Y$ or not). Yes to all your other questions. Anyways, did you try to solve any of these?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I did try solving it, but I am quite new to this topic. I tried to construct invariant measures on the doubling map and the tent map such that there is an isomorphism with an irrational rotation for at least one of them, but I cannot come up with any other measures than Dirak measure, the integral measure (the uniform density over the unit interval) and Lebesgue measure, which do not allow the isomorphism to work.